# Unable to inject one factory into another factory in angularjs 1 and send token to angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, authentication, dependency-injection, single-sign-on

I have an application which is a php application. I want this application to reside in my primary domain (primarydomain.com purposely for Single-Sign-On(to manage account details). Every user login here and upon successful login, redirect to one of my app hosted on a first.primarydomain.com. Upon redirection, authorize the user by checking if the user really logged in.
Now I have hosted an angularjs application in first.primarydomain.com

In my angularjs project, I have created a factory file which has 2 factory
1. Data
2. Auth.

The Data is for database operation while the Auth is meant for authorization check and logging out users.

Below is my code.

```js
App.js

 /* Init global settings and run the app */
app.run(["$rootScope", "settings", "$state", "$location", "Auth", function($rootScope, settings, $state, $location, Auth) {
  $rootScope.$state = $state; // state to be accessed from view
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
      if (!$rootScope.authenticated || $rootScope.authenticated==false){
        var user;
        Auth.isLoggedIn()
        user=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        console.log(user)
        if(!user){
          window.location="http://primarydomain.com/login"
        }else{
          //this.authenticated=true;
          //this.loggedUser=user;
          $rootScope.authenticated = true;
          $rootScope.loggedUser =user;
        } 
      }
      //console.log($state)  
    });
}]);
```

```
//Factory.js
//Data. factory
//do some database query
app.factory("Data", ['$http', '$location', function ($http, $q, $location) {

  var serviceBase = 'server/f3';

  var obj = {};

  obj.get = function (q) {
      //alert(q)
      return $http.get(serviceBase + q).then(function (results) {
          return results.data;
      });
  };
  obj.gets = function(q,config){
    return $http.get(serviceBase + q,config);
  }
  obj.post = function (q, object) {
      return $http.post(serviceBase + q, object).then(function (results) {
          return results.data;
      });
  };
  obj.posts = function (q, object) {
    return $http.post(serviceBase + q, object, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined,'Process-Data': false}
      }
    )
  .then(function (results) {
            return results.data;
        })
  };
  obj.put = function (q, object) {
      return $http.put(serviceBase + q, object).then(function (results) {
          return results.data;
      });
  };
  obj.delete = function (q) {
      return $http.delete(serviceBase + q).then(function (results) {
          return results.data;
      });
  };
  return obj;
}]);



app.factory('Auth', ['$http', '$location','Data', function ($http,$location,Data){
        var obj = {};

        obj.isLoggedIn = function(){
            var user=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
            if(!user){
                Data.get('/webpass/1').then(function(datas){

                    if(datas.type==1){
                        //alert('response good')
                        //console.log(datas.response)
                        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(datas.response)); 
                        return datas.response;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }else{
                //alert('deji')
                return (user)?user:false;   
            }            
        };

        obj.Logout= function(){
            //console.log('deji')
            Data.get('/logout').then(function(datas){
                //console.log(datas)
                if(datas.type==1){
                    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            });
        };
        return obj;
    }]);

<!-- end snippet -->

//Logout controllers
app.controller('LogoutController', function($rootScope, $scope, $location, Auth) {

    Auth.Logout();
    var user=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    if(!user){
        $rootScope.authenticated=false;
        $rootScope.loggedUser=null;
        window.location='http://primarydomain/login';
    }else{
        //alert('Unable to log user out')
        $location.path('/dashboard');
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

In the factory, none of the factory function can call the injected factory. It actually doesn't give any error but while tracking the execution flow, I realized that it doesn't even execute that part of the factory.

Another problem is that after successful login on the primarydomain.com, I want to send a token alongside the first.primarydomain.com which contains some user information and the access details. Please, how do I do this with angularjs 1.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning the values from isLoggedIn function. A simpler example of how it needs to work:

```
return $http.get(url).then((res) => {
  return res.data;
}
```

Notice both **return** used, since we also need to return a Promise as well as its value.

You have failed to return the Promise:

```
Data.get('/webpass/1').then(function(datas){
  /* Some code here */
  return datas.response;
});
```

Instead it should be:

```
return Data.get('/webpass/1').then(function(datas){
  /* Some code here */
  return datas.response;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I dont actually know what happened but I want to believed I didnt do it right. I actually works. thank you. But one more thing, is there a way to pass token to an angularjs application inform of session_id as an handshake from php to angularjs project?

Comment: You can make a call to PHP `$http.get('php/session.php').then((res) => {Session.create(res.data);});` and get back a session from `session_start();`, `$sess = array();`, `sess["session_id"] = $_SESSION['session_id'];`, `return $sess;` if that's what you are asking

Comment: Thank you so much and I really do appreciate you. Actually I have php application purposely for account registration and login control on my primary domain while my angularjs application is on another sub-domain. After a successful login on the primary domain, it redirects to the angularjs application on the subdomain. I need to pass a token to the angularjs application from the php application. How do achieve this? Is there anyway I can receive such token either by browser cookie or url parameter?

Comment: Security issues arise from any solution you try to achieve. Cross-domain sessions could be passed as a query in URL, but this will expose user's session. I suggest looking into Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing and [Custom Session Handlers](http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php)

Comment: Please, is there anyway to set a global or constant variable in angularjs?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing. `$rootScope` is a global scope that is watched on every frame, so using it is fine but can slow down your app. Setting some kind of session in a service and constantly updating or checking these values might be what you want in some cases. To detect any changes you want to broadcast constants `angular.constant('AUTH_EVENTS', {loginSuccess: 'auth-login-success'})` with `$rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);` and detect with  `$rootScope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess, your_function_callback);`

Comment: - don't forget to inject your constants if you will use them: `function YourService($rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS){ /* your code */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have any injection issues by changing

```
app.factory("Data", ['$http', '$location', function ($http, $q, $location) {
```

to

```
app.factory("Data", ['$http', '$q', '$location', function ($http, $q, $location) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Actually the Data factory is still working perfectly in another contest where I use it directly in any of my controller

Comment: Someone pls help. Does it mean nobody here still do angularjs? This is killing.